# Appium startActivity() Function

Tags: java, android, appium

I am new to Appium, In my code I have given required desired capabilities and wrote one test case that is working fine. Now I want to launch another App for second test in same code , how can I do that ?
I heard about startActivity(app-package,app Activity) but its not working, it says startActivity() not defined for Web Driver .

```
public class Calculator {
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
//Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "14085521650378");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2"); // This is package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
configurations specified in Desired Capabilities
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub"), capabilities); 
}
@Test
public void testCal(){
driver.findElement(By.name("2")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("+")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("4")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("=")).click();
}
@Test
public void Test2() {   driver.startActivity("appPackage", "com.tttk.apc","appActivity","com.tttk.apc.DWDemoActivity");
        for(int i=0; i<20;i++)
        driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ImageButton")).click();
}
@AfterClass
public void teardown(){
//close the app
driver.quit();
}}
```

Comment: please share the code you for the `driver` you are using and where you've been calling `startActivity` method.

Comment: @nullpointer please have a look on edited post

Comment: answered for the same, you shall use the method from the interface with driver of `AndroidDriver` type.

Comment: @nullpointer now Its not showing error in code, but when running code only first test case is running and in logs its saying "org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver"

Comment: true, you shall use `AppiumDriver` or `AndroidDriver` in order to use this capability form appium

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to use the method with a `WebDriver` instance.

The `startActivity` method is provided by an interface `StartsActivity` implemented by `AndroidDriver` only. So ideally this shall work :

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(<appPackage>, <appActivity>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void start() {
        try {
            ((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity("com.example.test", "com.example.LaunchApp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You have to enter your app package name and activity name to maximize the app.