# driver.startActivity (appPackage,dashboardappActivity) method cause crash after login with Google

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

```
@ BeforeTest

setup(){
// Desired App Capabilities for Appium with AndroidDriver
}

@ Test
// Click Login with Google button in home screen
// Login Activity is the Main Activity
androidDriver.findElementByName("LOGIN WITH GOOGLE").click();
androidDriver.findElementByName("Test Customer").click();

// Method to call Dashboard Activity after Login Activity
androidDriver.startActivity(testLoanAppPackageName,testLoanDashboardActivity);

// UI Element in Dashboard Screen
androidDriver.findElementByName("CREATE CREDIT REPORT CARD").click();
```

**Expected Behavior:**

App need to locate the ui element in dashboard screen

**Actual Behavior:**

App get crashed on calling start activity

Links I referred: [start activity in appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583945/appium-startactivity-function)

Comment: Can you please post error logs

Comment: @abhishesh Sorry for the delayed reply. I got NoSuchElementException because appium UI locator couldn't identify the UI element on dashboard screen. Alternatively app get crashed before identifying the UI element.

Comment: Basically while integrating login with google in native mobile application, device itself uses android web-view for a moment. We could use getcontexthandles() method to identify whether the view is native or webview. Device with older android versions doesn't allow to perform the switch between native to web-view and vice-versa. It results either app crash or some security exception. Latest device with chrome-stable web-view works as expected for native to web-view switch.